# 'this' keyword: Using it as parameter

Tags: java

I have started JAVA and doing serial communication using RxTx.

Referring to: 
http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Event_based_two_way_Communication
http://henrypoon.wordpress.com/2011/01/01/serial-communication-in-java-with-example-program/

In the 2nd link I am not able to decipher usage of **'this'**:
Can anyone please explain:

**Communicator.java**

```
public class Communicator implements SerialPortEventListener
{
  GUI window = null;
   ..
   ..
 public Communicator(GUI window)
    {
        this.window = window;
    }

...
..
}
```

**In GUI.java**

```
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Communicator communicator = null;
Communicator communicator = null;
    //KeybindingController object
    KeybindingController keybindingController = null;

    /** Creates new form GUI */
    public GUI() {
        initComponents();
        createObjects();
        communicator.searchForPorts();
        keybindingController.toggleControls();
        keybindingController.bindKeys();
    }

    private void createObjects()
    {
        **communicator = new Communicator(this);**
        keybindingController = new KeybindingController(this);
    }
...
..}
```

I am confused how this is used to create an object of Communicator class, as highlighted in above code(appearing **communicator = new Communicator(this);**)

Another confusion is:
**Communicator.java**

```
public class Communicator implements SerialPortEventListener
{ 
...
...
 public void connect()
    {
        String selectedPort = (String)window.cboxPorts.getSelectedItem();
        selectedPortIdentifier = (CommPortIdentifier)portMap.get(selectedPort);

        CommPort commPort = null;

        try
        {
            //the method below returns an object of type CommPort
            commPort = selectedPortIdentifier.open("TigerControlPanel", TIMEOUT);
            //the CommPort object can be casted to a SerialPort object
            serialPort = (SerialPort)commPort;
....
...}


 public void initListener()
    {
        try
        {
            **serialPort.addEventListener(this);**
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        }
        catch (TooManyListenersException e)
        {
            logText = "Too many listeners. (" + e.toString() + ")";
            window.txtLog.setForeground(Color.red);
            window.txtLog.append(logText + "\n");
        }
    }
....
}
```

Again I am confused with the use of 'this' here  (**serialPort.addEventListener(this);**)

I compared with the code at 
http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Event_based_two_way_Communication

there it suggests

```
...
InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
**serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialReader(in));**
...

 public static class SerialReader implements SerialPortEventListener 
    {
        private InputStream in;
        private byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        public SerialReader ( InputStream in )
        {
            this.in = in;
        }

        public void serialEvent(**SerialPortEvent arg0**) {
            int data;

            try
            {
                int len = 0;
                while ( ( data = in.read()) > -1 )
                {
                    if ( data == '\n' ) {
                        break;
                    }
                    buffer[len++] = (byte) data;
                }
                System.out.print(new String(buffer,0,len));
            }
            catch ( IOException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            }             
        }

    }
```

The description for addEventListener
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/

addEventListener

public abstract void addEventListener(SerialPortEventListener lsnr)
                               throws java.util.TooManyListenersException
Registers a SerialPortEventListener object to listen for SerialEvents. Interest in specific events may be expressed using the notifyOnXXX calls. The serialEvent method of SerialPortEventListener will be called with a SerialEvent object describing the event.

I want to know usage of this as how it is passing 'SerialPortEventListener lsnr' as the parameter to addEventListener in above code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` keyword is a reference to the current instance for which the code is being executed. So, since `this` is a reference, you can use it as any other reference. No problem in that.

Now let's take a look at your usage: -

```
new Communicator(this);
```

Since this statement is used inside the method of `GUI` class, so, `this` refers to the `instance of GUI`, currently executing the code. Now, by passing it to the constructor, you are simply passing the reference of current instance to it. And it's quite valid, since `Communicator` constructor takes a reference of type `GUI`: -

```
public Communicator(GUI window)
{
    this.window = window;
}
```

---

Now let's move ahead with the next statement:

```
serialPort.addEventListener(this);
```

Here, you are registering the `serialPort` with an `EventListener` which is referenced by `this`. Since, this is used inside the class - `Communicator`, which implements `SerialPortEventListener`, so basically you are registering to a `Communicator` instance, which is nothing but a `SerialPortEventListener`. So, you are registering to that event.

As far as your other code is concerned:

```
serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialReader(in));
```

Here, you have just used a new `instance` instead of `this`, since you are not inside `SerialReader` class. So, you don't have `this` reference to any `SerialReader` instance, and hence you need to create an object manually of that class.

So, there is no difference. Because, in any case, you are registering the class that implements `SerialPortEventListener` only.

Comment: I got it. Can you explain the second usage serialPort.addEventListener(this);

Comment: @GauravK. Added explanation.

Comment: got it. thanks mate. serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialReader(in)); is inside the class Communicator but it does not implement SerialPortEventListener. I guess datz why such expression.

Comment: @GauravK.. No, it's not inside `Communicator` class I assume. Since you haven't shown surrounding part. But, in this case, you are registering that `EventListener` through a different class that implements the `EventListener`, than the `communicator` class.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a pseudo-variable meaning 'the object that this method was called on' (or in a constructor: 'the object that is currently being constructed'). I have no idea what your problem with the code you posted is, because it includes lots of code that is apparently irrelevant to the question and I'm not going to start guessing where exactly your problem with them lies.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot to digest here to answer your original question, and I'm not sure it all relates, but let's tackle that specifically. The following code demonstrates use of `this` to remove ambiguity in the current scope:

```
public Communicator(GUI window)
{
    this.window = window;
}
```

`this` represents the current instance of the current class. So in your first instance of confusion, `this` is an instance of `Communicator` and so `this.window` exists. In the second case `this` is an instance of `GUI`, hence can be passed as a parameter to `Communicator`, as that's what it accepts.

Within that constructor for `Communicator`, because two things exist with the same name, and are to be used in the same scope, we need to disambiguate what we're doing. And we do that by saying "assign the foreign `window` thing to our local, known, owned `window` thing."

Think of a group of people, with numerous John's, and you simply shouting that name. Who would look to respond? What if you pointed, or there was some other indicator, such as the right John recognises you when they all look? `this` is that indicator, giving the specificity required to make something distinct from another.

Otherwise imagine the confusion of trying to assign `window` to `window`. Do we mean assign the local version to the local version, the parameter to the parameter, the parameter to the local version, or the local version to the parameter?

Comment: I completely understand what u explained. I want to know the usage of 'this' at highlighted lines . communicator = new Communicator(this);serialPort.addEventListener(this);

Comment: @GauravK I just added a little on `this` in context.